# Every plagiarism checker that I use, tells me I'm plagiarizing...?

Tags: quotations

“Jack was on top of the sow, stabbing downward with his knife… Then Jack found the throat and the hot blood spouted over his hands. The sow collapsed under them and they were heavy and fulfilled upon her” (Golding 135).

In between "with his knife" and "Then Jack" is still the same quote. It's just separated because there was another part that wasn't relevant to the quote.

Comment: If you are quoting and have cited the source- you're not plagiarizing.

Comment: I'd imagine lots of "plagiarism detectors" just flag anything that is in another text, whether it's in quotes or not. The program can't think.

Comment: This isn't the right site for this question. Possibly [Academia.se] might be okay, but you'd have to phrase it in a way that is relevant for post-graduate studies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not the right site for this question.

Answer (score 2):

What your checker may object to is the form. I can't speak to other stylesheets, but MLA calls for ellipsis points which you introduce to be enclosed in square brackets, like this:

> Jack was on top of the sow, stabbing downward with his knife […] Then Jack found the throat and the hot blood spouted over his hands.

This assures the reader that the ellipsis points are yours, not something present in the original.